# Discord.py progress bar

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py, progress-bar

Is there any way to make beautiful progress bar and embed it into message.

Here's one example of what I want to make:

[image: Discord progress bar example]

I know I can make an ASCII-style progress bar but I want exactly the same as on the pictire. Thanks!

Comment: It's already answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66886200/how-do-you-make-a-progress-bar-and-put-it-on-an-image/66887674#66887674