# TensorBoard display ground truth with detection

Tags: object, tensorflow, detection, tensorboard, bounding-box

I'm using TensorFlow model repo for object detection. For evaluation, I'm using Tensorboard which displays mAP and the result - predicted bounding box for detected object.
I would like to display the ground truth bounding box along with the predicted one. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, there is already API for that.

https://github.com/tensorflow/models/issues/2596

Answer (score 3):

it seems like you seek to display the ground truth bounding box next to the predicted box for object detection in TensorBoard. I'm assuming you are using the [image dashboard](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorboard#image-dashboard). Here is one idea.

You can pass the bytes of the original image into a [py_func](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/py_func), which lets you wrap a python function and use it as a TensorFlow op.

Within the `py_func`, you can render boxes on top of the image say using `matplotlib` (using `patches.Rectangle`):
[matplotlib: how to draw a rectangle on image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37435369/matplotlib-how-to-draw-a-rectangle-on-image)

And then, you can pass those bytes into an image summary op. This GitHub project offers an example: https://github.com/vahidk/EffectiveTensorflow/blob/master/README.md#prototyping-kernels-and-advanced-visualization-with-python-ops