# python multicolored background

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

How do I use matplotlib.pyplot to colour the background of my plot based on an array (of True/False's)?

So for example, if my array was (T,F,F,F,T,T) and I choose the colours 'red' and 'blue', I need the background to be a red column, 3 blue colomns, followed by 2 more reds.

```
N = 2000
tf = np.random.normal(size = N)
ctf = np.array([np.sum(tf[:1+i]) for i in range(N)])
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
tf2 = tf[None,:]
ax.imshow(tf2, cmap='RdYlGn', aspect = 'auto')
ax.plot(ctf,'k')
```

Comment: Take a look at `pcolor` or `imshow`. Make sure your input is 2 dimensional though (even if one dimension is only 1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [imshow](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.imshow.html):

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
data = np.array([True, False, True])[ None, :]
ax.imshow(data, cmap = 'RdBu', aspect="auto")
ax.axis('off')
fig.show()
```

edit: swapped axis to produce columns
edit2: add larger imshow

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
N = 2000
tf = np.random.normal(size = N)
ctf = np.array([np.sum(tf[:1+i]) for i in range(N)])
fig, ax = plt.subplots(2, sharex = 'all', \
                       gridspec_kw = dict(\
                                         height_ratios = [5, 1]))
tf2 = tf[None,:]
ax[0].plot(ctf,'k')
ax[1].imshow(tf2, cmap='RdYlGn', aspect = 'auto')
plt.subplots_adjust(hspace = 0)
```

edit 3:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
N = 2000
tf = np.random.normal(size = N)
ctf = np.array([np.sum(tf[:1+i]) for i in range(N)])
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

tf2 = tf[None,:]
ax.plot(ctf,'k')
ax.imshow(tf2, cmap='RdYlGn', aspect = 'auto', extent =[0, ctf.shape[0], ctf.min(), ctf.max()])
```

[image]
[image]

[image]

Comment: Is this supposed to work with a really long array for Data? I tried and it gives me just a line

Comment: Yes, but depending on the size of the array the resolution may not scale. I would recommend scaling the imshow with either scale = 'auto' or resizing the plot. Alternatively you may want to use multiple columns if the data is really long. This can be achieved by providing a 2d array as input to imshow.

Comment: You will want to use `aspect="auto"`. I took the freedom to edit the answer.

Comment: I get 'AttributeError: Unknown property scale'.      edit: just saw your edit. Let me try that.

Comment: Yes my bad, meant aspect.

Comment: Thanks. That work. However when I try to draw another plot on top the height of the columns stays the same. This makes it look like a coloured line because the plot on top goes from -10 to 10. How can I fix that?

Comment: Is this on the same axis or on a different one? Can you include the code above?

Comment: Also, why is the y-axis upside-down? It goes from -0.5 at the bottom to 0.5 at the top.

Comment: The reason why it is so small is that the imshow data is plotted on the range(0,1) since it only has one row. I am not entirely sure what you want to plot. But you can either create two axis to enlarge the imshow, or create vertical markers on the graph.  Edited my code above

Comment: What I wanted is plotting ctf with a multicoloured background. The background would indicate the regions where ctf is increasing or decreasing. However what you did works too. Thanks a lot for your time.

Comment: omg! Thank you so much. That's exactly what I wanted. I wish I could upvote twice.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want to draw rectangles on your plot.  (See [matplotlib: how to draw a rectangle on image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37435369/matplotlib-how-to-draw-a-rectangle-on-image)) If you want to have the Rectangles behind some other data, set their `zorder` to a negative number when you create them.