# Drawing a rectangle with Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm writing a python function to draw a simple rectangle, the vertex points are parameters. Well, this does not work correctly and I can't seem to find out why its plotting all over the place.
EDIT:
as for my imports. So sp is sympy. As for the expected result to draw a rectangle of course.

```
%matplotlib inline
import sympy as sp
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math

def draw_rectangle(P1,P2,P3,P4):
    p1, p2, p3, p4 = sp.Point(P1[0], P1[1]), sp.Point(P2[0], P2[1]), sp.Point(P3[0], P3[1]), 
    sp.Point(P4[0], P4[1])
    plt.plot(p1,p2)
    plt.plot(p2,p3)
    plt.plot(p3,p4)
    plt.plot(p4,p1)

P1=[20,30]
P2=[40,30]
P3=[40,60]
P4=[20,60]
draw_rectangle(P1,P2,P3,P4)
```

Actual Outcome with this code
[image: Actual Outcome with this code]

Comment: Welcome to SO. The vertex points are all the same, that does not seem right. And what is `sp`? Maybe shapely? Please provide reproducible code, including imports, expected outcome, and actual outcome.

Comment: sorry, copy pasting error there. editet my post with the actual vertex points also added the imports.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [matplotlib: how to draw a rectangle on image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37435369/matplotlib-how-to-draw-a-rectangle-on-image)

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37435369/matplotlib-how-to-draw-a-rectangle-on-image

Comment: @cvanelteren No, saw that one already. Problem is in need to use those four vertex points

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The delivery of the x-y coordinates is mixed up in your code. `p1` is still in the same form as `P1`, i.e., an x-y pair. But matplotlib [`plt.plot()`](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.plot.html) expects a list of x-values followed by a list of y-values. Hence, this misunderstanding - matplotlib interpreted in `plt.plot(p1,p2)` `p1` as two x-values and `p2` as two y-values. So, we have to chain the x- and the y-values together before plotting.

```
import sympy as sp
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def draw_rectangle(P1,P2,P3,P4):
    p1, p2 = sp.Point(P1[0], P1[1]), sp.Point(P2[0], P2[1])
    p3, p4 = sp.Point(P3[0], P3[1]), sp.Point(P4[0], P4[1])
    plt.plot(*zip(p1,p2))
    plt.plot(*zip(p2,p3))
    plt.plot(*zip(p3,p4))
    plt.plot(*zip(p4,p1))
    #or alternatively
    #plt.plot(*zip(p1, p2, p3, p4, p1))

P1=[20,30]
P2=[40,30]
P3=[40,60]
P4=[20,60]

draw_rectangle(P1,P2,P3,P4)
plt.show()
```

Sample output:

[image]

However, it remains unclear why you converted your data into `sympy` points before plotting. You could have directly used `P1`, `P2`,..., but maybe this is required for some other program parts we are not aware of. Or you actually wanted to use another `sympy` function, not `sp.point`, but I don't speak fluent `sympy`, so cannot comment on that.

Comment: nice thank you very much. The explaination really worked for me. Works just fine now.