# Creating a neat output including text boxes and text in specific positions?

Tags: python, data-visualization

I'm no sure what the right terminology to use for this ask is, but i want to create a python output that will look something like this:

[image]

With the intent of having some Data extracted from specific cells of a dataframe fill in the TEXT section of the image. Obviously i want the data to not be hard-coded so i can change it as per the topic. What packages even do this? I've never explored the "visual" component side of python before.

Comment: [Pillow](https://pypi.org/project/Pillow/) can achieve this

Comment: seem to be running into a separate issue with Pillow, where jupyter notebooks has it installed but it doesn't seem to be able to import it. Is that just a version issue?

Comment: Haven't used jupyter so won't be able to say with certainty what could be causing this.

Comment: if you get error message with Pillow then you should show it in your question. Maybe you have two Python installed and you installed Pillow in one Python and you run code with other Python. OR it needs to install some C/C++ library which is not part of Python.

Comment: in you use jupyter and work with data then you probably know module `matplotlib` which is used for plots - but it should have also functions to draw rectangles and text. You have to only read documentation.

Comment: Stackoverflow: [python - matplotlib: how to draw a rectangle on image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37435369/matplotlib-how-to-draw-a-rectangle-on-image)